# Падежные окончания

Tags: падежи, орфография

7 и 8 ноября были праздничные выходные дни. 
7 и 8 ноября были праздничными выходными днями.
Как лучше? И почему? Спасибо за ответы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Из книги Розенталя "Говорите и пишите по-русски правильно"
«Её сестра звалась Татьяна...» — «Итак, она звалась Татьяной»
1.
2.  В соседних строфах из пушкинского «Евгения Онегина» в составном сказуемом при глаголе звалась именная часть употреблена то в форме именительного падежа: Её сестра звалась Татьяна, то в форме творительного падежа: Итак, она звалась Татьяной. Обе конструкции равноправны: Его звали... Григорием Александровичем Печориным (М. Лермонтов); Звали её Фаня (А. Гайдар).
3.  Обе падежные формы именной части составного сказуемого встречаются также при глаголе-связке быть, например: И в семье его Савельич был свой человек (П. Мельников-Печерский); У Ивашкиных он был своим человеком (А. Чехов). При этом часто форма именительного падежа именной части составного сказуемого обозначает устойчивый признак подлежащего, постоянно присущую ему качественную характеристику, а форма творительного падежа обычно указывает на временный признак.
4.  Например, мы скажем: Печорин был офицер (таким мы его видим на протяжении всего романа «Герой нашего времени»); о человеке же, который раньше служил в армии, а потом демобилизовался, мы говорим: Он был офицером. Сравните у А.С. Пушкина: Германн был сын обрусевшего немца (постоянный признак); Бопре в отечестве своём был парикмахером, потом в Пруссии солдатом (временный признак).
5.  Впрочем, начиная с конца XIX в. употребление именной части составного сказуемого в форме именительного падежа идёт на убыль, и в наши дни обычны конструкции с формой творительного падежа: Он всегда был моим другом (хотя речь идёт, очевидно, об устойчивом признаке).

Answer (score 1):

...7 и 8 ноября  праздничные выходные дни

Comment: Танюша, в данном случае "7 и 8 ноября были праздничные выходные дни" - это и всё предложение. Перед числами ничего не предполагается.

Answer (score 1):

В составном именном сказуемом, именная часть которого выражена именем существительным, предпочтителен творительный падеж.

Comment: Виктор, а не можете кинуть ссылочку на какого-нибудь Розенталя, где об этом идет речь? Пожалуйста... И разъясните, что здесь входит в составное именное сказуемое. Хочу раз и навсегда с этим разобраться.

Comment: Для Екатерина2012. Посмотрите у Розенталя "Справочник по правописанию и литературной правке" $177 Формы сказуемого, пункт 3

Answer (score 1):

Отвечу ориентируясь лишь на собственное чувство языка.
В творительном падеже фраза выглядит более завершённой и самодостаточной. "7 и 8 ноября были праздничными выходными днями, поэтому я не вышел на работу".
В падеже именительном завершённости уже нет. Фразу так и хочется дополнить чем-то вроде - "7 и 8 ноября были праздничные выходные дни. Мы решили выбраться на дачу, чтобы насладиться последними деньками осени. Я собрал...". Подобное построение позволяет лучше передать сопричастность к событию, что хорошо в художественном или публицистическом стилях речи, но накладывает на произносящего дополнительные обязательства по раскрытию подобного склонения.
В общем, если сомневаетесь лучше употребить более нейтральный творительный падеж, хотя всё вышенаписанное исключительно мои измышления, доверять которым нет никакого основания.